# Drawbacks of dielectric wall accelerators

Tags: electrostatics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, particle-accelerators

Wby are [dielectric wall accelerators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_wall_accelerator) not used as a replacement to conventional particle accelerators? How “efficient” are they in accelerating particles compared to conventional accelerators?

Answer (score 0):

In a [(2009) article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244914271_The_Dielectric_Wall_Accelerator), and [here 2012](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/IPAC2013/papers/thoab201.pdf),  it seems to be still at the design stage, and the use  expected in the  [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_wall_accelerator) are for low energy  therapy uses. This implies that the technique is not able to deliver energies needed in the TeV range for study of  particle interactions.

Comment: from what I see from the second link the designs reach 20MeV/meter